# Nutch Selenium Interactive plugin ignores the chromedriver configuration

Tags: selenium, solr, selenium-chromedriver, nutch

I configured nutch-site.xml for a local crawl with selenium interactive plugin included.

I have configured only the basics, so the configuration is quite simple (properties from conf/nutch-site.xml).

```
<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-interactiveselenium|urlfilter-(regex|validator)|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
  <description>Regular expression naming plugin directory names to
  include.  Any plugin not matching this expression is excluded.
  By default Nutch includes plugins to crawl HTML and various other
  document formats via HTTP/HTTPS and indexing the crawled content
  into Solr.  More plugins are available to support more indexing
  backends, to fetch ftp:// and file:// URLs, for focused crawling,
  and many other use cases.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>selenium.driver</name>
  <value>chrome</value>
  <description>
    A String value representing the flavour of Selenium
    WebDriver() to use. Currently the following options
    exist - 'firefox', 'chrome', 'safari', 'opera' and 'remote'.
    If 'remote' is used it is essential to also set correct properties for
    'selenium.hub.port', 'selenium.hub.path', 'selenium.hub.host',
    'selenium.hub.protocol', 'selenium.grid.driver', 'selenium.grid.binary'
    and 'selenium.enable.headless'.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>webdriver.chrome.driver</name>
  <value>/Users/theo/DISKS/Work/PNR/chromedriver</value>
  <description>The path to the ChromeDriver binary</description>
</property>
```

This is from the nutch logs:

```
2020-08-17 23:40:57,427 ERROR interactiveselenium.Http - Failed to get protocol output
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /root/chromedriver
        at org.apache.nutch.protocol.selenium.HttpWebClient.getDriverForPage(HttpWebClient.java:153)
        at org.apache.nutch.protocol.interactiveselenium.HttpResponse.readPlainContent(HttpResponse.java:401)
        at org.apache.nutch.protocol.interactiveselenium.HttpResponse.<init>(HttpResponse.java:280)
        at org.apache.nutch.protocol.interactiveselenium.Http.getResponse(Http.java:57)
        at org.apache.nutch.protocol.http.api.HttpBase.getProtocolOutput(HttpBase.java:383)
        at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherThread.run(FetcherThread.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /root/chromedriver
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:146)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:141)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
        at org.apache.nutch.protocol.selenium.HttpWebClient.createChromeWebDriver(HttpWebClient.java:182)
        at org.apache.nutch.protocol.selenium.HttpWebClient.getDriverForPage(HttpWebClient.java:89)
        ... 5 more
2020-08-17 23:40:57,430 INFO  fetcher.FetcherThread - FetcherThread 46 fetch of https://www.amazon.in/ failed with: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /root/chromedriver
```

Why is it looking in the wrong place?

In fact.. it is referring to other settings from nutch-site.xml correctly. Once I included the protocol-interactiveselenium, it started using selenium for the fetch.

Also, earlier it was looking for /root/geckodriver which is the firefox driver. Once I changed the selenium.driver to chrome, it started looking for /root/chromedriver.

So, far so good. Now, I went and changed the webdriver.chrome.driver property, but that doesn't seem to be considered.

Comment: @SebastianNagel Thanks. Seems it considers "selenium.grid.binary" even if it is not running in remote mode.

Comment: Thanks, for the confirmation. The issue is tracked as [NUTCH-2825](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2825).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [code of HttpWebClient](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/f3afee07af94beb43ac3c4ba784af69a7d4323dc/src/plugin/lib-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/HttpWebClient.java#L173) - the property `webdriver.chrome.driver` is overwritten by the value of `selenium.grid.binary`. Pointing the latter to your chromedrive should work. Please open an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NUTCH, not clear whether this is a bug or a documentation issue. But should be addressed anyway.